# Scala manifest not Found Spark Streaming

Tags: java, maven, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I'm new to Spark Streaming, 
From Spark Streaming I created a direct stream to Kafka Using KafkaUtils. like below

```
jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(KafkaConfig.getInstance().getBatchDuration()));

HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();

kafkaParams.put(KafkaConstants.ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_STRING, zookeeperHost + ":" + zookeeperPort);
kafkaParams.put(KafkaConstants.METADATA_BROKER_LIST_STRING, bootstrapHost  + ":" + bootstrapPort);
kafkaParams.put(KafkaConstants.GROUP_ID_STRING, groupId);

HashSet<String> topicSet = new HashSet<String>();
topicSet.add(topic);

JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> topicStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, String.class,
        String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topicSet);

JavaDStream<String> topicMessages = topicStream.map(Tuple2::_2);
topicMessages.print()
```

When I tried to run the job It is throwing below error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/ClassManifest

Full Stack is here :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   scala/reflect/ClassManifest   at
>   kafka.utils.Log4jController$.(Log4jController.scala:29)     at
>   kafka.utils.Log4jController$.(Log4jController.scala)  at
>   kafka.utils.Logging$class.$init$(Logging.scala:29)    at
>   kafka.api.TopicMetadataRequest$.(TopicMetadataRequest.scala:28)
>     at
>   kafka.api.TopicMetadataRequest$.(TopicMetadataRequest.scala)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitionMetadata(KafkaCluster.scala:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getPartitions(KafkaCluster.scala:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
>     at
>   consumer.spark.KafkaConsumer.consumeMessages(KafkaConsumer.java:103)
>     at consumer.spark.KafkaConsumer.executeStream(KafkaConsumer.java:142)
>     at
>   consumer.spark.KafkaConsumerService.main(KafkaConsumerService.java:27)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.reflect.ClassManifest     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 23 more

Here is my pom.xml

```
<!-- Scala version -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
</dependency>

<!--Spark Core -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!--Spark Streaming -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!--Kafka -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `Scala version -> 2.10.3` and you have written `artifactID with 2.11`. You should change artifactID to `2.10` for every dependency and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

change scala version to 2.11 in your pom.xml it will work

Answer (score 0):

Beside changing scala version as the answers above, you should check the scala version of scala-related dependencies (like: spark-streaming...), so please check scala version of the dependency before including them in your project.

[Please check the scala version before including the dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so6Cz.png)